# Multiple Inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

There are couple of questions regarding this.But I am still not clear about this. Consider this multiple inheritance.

```
class Base1 
{ 
   public: 
     Base1(); 
     virtual ~Base1(); 
     virtual void speakClearly(); 
     virtual Base1 *clone() const; 
   protected: 
     float data_Base1; 
}; 

class Base2 
{ 
   public: 
     Base2(); 
     virtual ~Base2(); 
     virtual void mumble(); 
     virtual Base2 *clone() const; 
   protected: 
     float data_Base2; 
}; 

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 
{ 
   public: 
     Derived(); 
     virtual ~Derived(); 
     virtual Derived *clone() const; 
   protected: 
     float data_Derived; 
};
```

and consider these two statements

```
Base1 *pbase1 = new Derived; 
Base2 *pbase2 = new Derived;
```

The book inside the C++ Object model states that in one of the optimization.

The vtable of pbase1 subobject and Derived share the same vtable. Exact phrase in the book

"Base 1 being leftmost, it already points to the beginning of the Derived class object "

How does this happen? I understand this will change if I change the order of inheritance as

```
class Derived : public Base2, public Base1
```

But I dont understand how this is done by the compiler. Can anybody explain how pbase1 and derived share the same v_table?

Comment: Being v_tables usually implemented as pointer offsets in an array (but doesn't need to be), I just guess that they can share the v_table for objects of class `Derived` because the compiler can merge `Base1` and `Base2`v_tables at compile-time. What should be strange about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all very implementation defined, but typically, a compiler
will lay out `Derived` as

```
Base1: vptr
Base1: data
Base2: vptr
Base2: data
Derived: data
```

The address of the `Derived` is the address of the whole, thus
the same physical address as that of `Base1`.  The initial part
of the vtable for `Derived` will be identical with that of
`Base1`, and the Base1: vptr will in fact point to the vtable of
`Derived`.

If you inverse `Base1` and `Base2` in the declaration, the
compiler will inverse their roles above.  (Typically.  There's
nothing in the standard which would prevent the compiler from
arranging the bases in alphabetical order, or putting the
derived data first, but I've never heard of a compiler which did
so.)

Answer (score 1):

Think to a class as having some "hideen members" that preceed the ones you declare, giving a layout like this one:

- The vtable pointer
- The fisrt base

  - It's vtable pointer
  - It's own members
- The second base

  - It's vtable pointer
  - It's own members
- The derived members

Now the problem is "where should the pointers point to?"

Since all the functions are available in the most derived object, you can create an "array of function pointers" for:

- dtor,
- speakClearly
- clone
- mumble

This table works the same for `Derived` and `Base1` (it has just to ignore the last line), but doesn't for `Base2`, that has to see just

- dtor
- clone
- mumble

with a different indexing than the previous (that's why it needs to be different).

Because of this fact, there is no need to distinguish between the Derived and first-base table instances (Of course, we can do the same reasoning starting from the last base and differentiating the previous ones ... but we have to start somewhere)

The compiler will hence "compact" the implementation, by creating just a table having the first base virtual functions plus all the others, and other distinct tables for the other bases, than it will initialize all the pointer to the most derived implementation the the virtual functions.

The layout will be

1. Derived vtable
2. Base1 members
3. Base2 versus Derived vtable
4. Base2 members
5. Derived members

Now, `new Derived` will just create that sketch, and:

- If given to `Derived*` will make it point to 1.
- If given to `Base1*` will make it point to 1. (jusk like Derived, but "shorter")
- If given to `Base2*` will make it point to 3.